# react js, why is this undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have this array that is type Technology and type undefined and its making things very difficult. For example I am trying to compare this array to another array and it complains that it might be undefined etc. So I am wondering why is this undefined and how to prevent this.

This component is my main component that gets the data from the server and creates 2 different arrays holding all the data from each collection.

```
const App = ():JSX.Element => {

  //Data from server recieve both collections in one get
  const onResponse = (result:JSONData):void => {
    // data received from Web API
    //console.table(result);
    setTechnologies(result.technologies);
    setAll_Courses(result.all_courses);
    setLoading(false);
  };
  //For error
  const onError = (message:string):void => console.log("*** Error has occured during AJAX data transmission: " + message);
  // ----------------------------------- setting state variables
  const [technologies, setTechnologies] = React.useState<Technology[]>([]);
  const [all_courses, setAll_Courses] = React.useState<AllCourses[]>([]);
  // Loading
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false); 
  // Routing and history
  const history:any = useHistory();
  const route:string = useLocation().pathname;

  React.useEffect(():void => {
    getJSONData(COURSE_SCRIPT, onResponse, onError);
  }, []);
```

And in my other component I make an array from the data that matches this _id in the collection of technologies. So I can then work in this component with that specific document, because I need to edit the data and display data etc. Everything is difficult because its undefined.

```
const EditTechnology = ({technologies, all_courses, visible}:ViewProps):JSX.Element => {

let { id } = useParams<{id:string}>();
    let edit_Technology:(Technology | undefined) = technologies.find(item => item._id === id) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give props a default value in child components to prevent undefined errors, like this

```
const EditTechnology = ({technologies = [], all_courses = [], visible}:ViewProps):JSX.Element => {

  let { id } = useParams<{id:string}>();
  let edit_Technology:(Technology | undefined) = technologies.find(item => item._id === id);
}
```

Or put it in onResponse, in this way, you don’t need to add many default value to each child components

```
const onResponse = (result:JSONData):void => {
  // data received from Web API
  //console.table(result);
  setTechnologies(result.technologies || []);
  setAll_Courses(result.all_courses || []);
  setLoading(false);
};
```

Comment: I tried this and did not solve my problem, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe depends on method find

```js
const bad =  ['you','will','get', 'undefined', 'if', 'you', 'looking']
 .find(e => e === 'something else')

const good =  ['now', 'you', 'will','find', 'it']
 .find(e => e === 'it')

console.log('for `something else` -', bad)
console.log('for `it` -', good)
```

Comment: this does not make any sense to me, they are both the same just one has more values

Comment: one hasn't value, other has value which we looking, if find method can't get value then it returns undefined

Comment: аre you sure item._id === id exists?